# Liability for our children

Tags: meaning-in-context

> What should our liabillity for our children be?
>
> What should our liability be for our children?

In these sentence , Is there any meaning difference. For our children is used after liability in first sentence and it is used in the end in the second sentence? Does place of “ for our children” change meaning ?

Comment: I don't think you mean liability. That is a technical,legal word. I think you mean: To what extent should we be responsible for our children.

Comment: What is our **duty to** our children?

Comment: Do you want the grammar or the semantics of the nouns?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Liability

**What should** our **liability for this product** be?

OR

**What should** our **liability be** for this product?

Both are grammatical and mean the same thing.

Structure:

What should X for Y be?
OR
What should X be for Y?

Both are 100% grammatical in English.

Comment: The naysayers here are 100% mistaken. They need to learn English before downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

Not much difference in meaning, but a potential difference in emphasis. The former might be used in a context where our children had already been among the topics of discourse, while the latter might be used where the speaker's intent is to introduce the topic, and to focus on it's significance.

But for many speakers, the two versions would be interchangeable.

(And I agree with @Lambie about *liability*. I hadn't mentioned it because your question was about word order, not word choice.)